# Check if a decimal number is within a range

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, decimal

This might be easy, but I just have to make sure how to do it right. How do I check if a `decimal` number is within a range?

I have two decimal numbers:

```
Dim minFactor As Decimal = 1.95
Dim maxFactor As Decimal = 2.05

Dim varResult as decimal
```

Now I want to check I the calculated `varResult` is within the range of the two factors. If it is, return `true`.

How is the most correct practice?

I tried:

```
Select Case varResult 
    Case 1.95 To 2.05 
        Unit1 = True 
    Case Else 
        Unit1 = False 
End Select
```

Comment: Select Case varResult
                    Case 1.95 To 2.05
                        Unit1 = True               
                    Case Else
                        Unit1 = False
                End Select

Comment: Ahh.. sorry that code couldn't be formatted

Comment: you can use : Decimal.Compare

Comment: Select Case can be a good option, especially if you have many different ranges to check...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply use the [`>=` and `<=` operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.op_greaterthanorequal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
If varResult >= minFactor AndAlso varResult <= maxFactor Then
    ' ...
End If
```

But since you're using ASP.NET i assume that your question targets validation of user-input. So i would use a [`RangeValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.aspx) which is made for this purpose:

```
<asp:RangeValidator id="Range1"
           ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
           MaximumValue="2.05" 
           MinimumValue="1.95" 
           Type="Double"
           EnableClientScript="false"
           Text="The value must be from 1.95 to 2.05!"
           runat="server"/>
```

Note that you also need a `RequiredFieldVFalidator` when no input at all is invalid.

Comment: Hi, it's at check up within a code block where the following code is dependant of the true/false value of varResult

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the value to each range:

```
If varResult >= minFactor And varResult <= maxFactor Then ...
```

You can use the `>=` and `<=` operator if the range limit should be inclusive, and the `>` and `<` operators if the range limits should be exclusive.

If you have more than one range, and one range takes over where the other ends, it's common to make the lower bound inclusive and the upper bound exclusive, that way there is no value where the ranges overlap:

```
Dim minRange1 As Decimal = 1.95
Dim maxRange1 As Decimal = 2.05
Dim minRange2 As Decimal = 2.05
Dim maxRange2 As Decimal = 2.95

If varResult >= minRange1 And varResult < maxRange1 Then
  ...
ElseIf varResult >= minRange2 And varResult < maxRange2 Then
  ...
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple :

```
If (varResult < maxFactor && varResult > minFactor )
     return true; 
else 
     return false;
```

Thanks